# Oracle/ PLSQL condition like 'string' || '%'

Tags: oracle, plsql

Why this

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT
WHERE FULLNAME LIKE 'Nguyen' || '%'
```

as the same

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT
WHERE FULLNAME LIKE 'Nguyen%'
```

How does the first one work?

Comment: Because concatenation operator(`||`) has higher precedence than SQL conditions (`LIKE` operator in this case).  [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators001.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`||` is `concatenation operator`. Oracle will first perform concatenation and then will use `LIKE` to match the pattern. Hence operationally it will be same as the second one.

However you should use the second one as it will be  more efficient in performance and easy to read.

First one has extra overhead to append two strings before using `LIKE` to match the pattern.

Comment: `||` is not an append operator - it is the (string) [concatenation operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm).

Comment: The overhead of evaluating the result of a static expression like `'Nguyen' || '%'` is almost nil and may be safely ignored. Overhead would only apply if the expression was based on, say, a column in a table.

Answer (score 0):

the first one catenate 'Nguyen' and '%' through the pipes '||' in first place.
Because you don't have any space like 'Nguyen ' or ' %', it's the same as 'Nguyen%'.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between these two:
Here the double pipe(||) is just a concatenation of expression.

Before db evaluate against like parameter, it concatenates

Hence both of those are same.

Answer (score 0):

Both are same, as || operator concats 'Nguyen' and '%', it will be more helpful if you want to concat parameterize variable like below

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT
WHERE FULLNAME LIKE :name || '%'
```